# How to create a named vector for color palette?

Tags: r, visualization, heatmap

I want to create a color palette for `kirp`, `kirc`, `kich`, and `normal` to plot a heatmap using the ComplexHeatmap library. According to the documentation, color can be specified as:

> Colors corresponding to value. If the mapping is discrete, the value of col should be a named vector

However, my code did not output the proper colors as specified with the HEX code.

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(circlize)
library(magick)

mat = as.matrix(expr)    
type = colnames(mat)

ha = HeatmapAnnotation(type = type, annotation_name_side = "left")
SingleAnnotation(name="Sample type", value=c("Normal", "kirp", "kirc", "kich"), col=c(kirp="#FF0000", kirc="#FFA026", kich="#7E2E1F", normal="#64F0F0"))
```

Documentation:

https://rdrr.io/bioc/ComplexHeatmap/man/SingleAnnotation.html

Comment: Looks like the output of SingleAnnotation is not assigned to a variable to be used by draw?

Comment: `col_aan  <- SingleAnnotation(name = "Sample type", value = c("Normal", "kirp", "kirc", "kich"), col = c(kirp = "#FF0000", kirc = "#FFA026", kich = "#7E2E1F", normal = "#64F0F0"))
ha <- HeatmapAnnotation(type = type, annotation_name_side = "left", col = col_aan)
`might help